# How to read Z == 0. - 0.00162663 W

Tags: simplifying-expressions, numerics

I am solving a set of three linear equations with four variables and found out the values of `X`, `Y` and `Z` in terms of `W`. My `Z` value is showing `Z == 0. - 0.00162663 W`. What do it mean actually? I'm confused about the `0.` part before the negative sign. If it is the error part, then why there is no value after the `0.` part? Or is it any *Mathematica* technique which I am not getting actually? I want to know how this value can be read?

Comment: I'd typically interpret that as there being a small numerical part which numerically cancels out to zero but isn't necessarily clearly provable to be equal to zero. Then the W term is subtracted from it. If you could provide the system, saying exactly what that term means would be easier, but chances are if you could perform the problem using only exact numbers it would disappear regardless.

Comment: To complement @eyorble's remarks, the `0.` is the floating-point number zero. The designers of *Mathematica* chose not to eliminate such a term in a `Plus[...]` expression. One way it is signifcant in the system is in the difference between `Precision[0. + x]` and `Precision[x]`. Paradoxically `0. x` evaluates to `0.`, but in this case, the `Precision` is maintained. A common way to get rid of unwanted `0.` terms is to use `Chop[]` with an appropriate tolerance. Usually such terms are harmless. I sometimes use `expr /. zero_ /; zero == 0 -> 0` to replace zero terms with the integer `0`.

Comment: `Z == 0. - 0.00162663 W // Rationalize` would also get rid of the`0.`

Comment: thanks all. Juggling with different arbitrary values as well I find out that as all of you has suggested this zero is insignificant here. It is the same as writing Z == - 0.00162663 W i.e. the Z can be expressed only by the W term and there is no constant or other function present in it's expression.